# How to remove fields from ZfcUser that aren't needed?

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

Just getting my hands dirty with a new ZF2 site, and I'm working on integrating the ZfcUser module. I have it working great out-of-the-box but I'm now trying to customize it.  I was able to create my own `Entity\User`, and to add fields and have them save to my user table, but I am having a lot of trouble removing the fields I don't need.

Specifically, I am not using the username or `display_name` fields. I have `enable_username` and `enable_display_name` set to false, and they don't show up in the register form, but I get an error when I don't have those fields in the database table itself:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'username' in 'field list'"
```

It seems this is because my user entity implements `UserInterface` which includes these fields, but this appears to be a requirement of the UserHydrator. I'm hesitant to try to customize or overwrite too much as I'm not well-versed in ZF2 yet or how these various pieces work together, but it seems silly to keep these extra fields in the table if they're always going to be null. Any ideas?

Comment: Removing indeed is a little more complicated, but that's why there are options to simply not use them. `ZfCommons` is an initiatiave to provide Common-Purpose-Modules. The `display_name` is one of those pretty common things. Just don't use them. Database-wise they are `NULL` so DB-Size doesn't really matter either ;)

Comment: Thanks, Sam, that's true. I just like to remove clutter =)

Answer (score 1):

use your own entity for users

change the zfcuser entity in your module config array ->

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
       'zfcuser_entity' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'paths' => __DIR__ . '/../src/YourModule/Entity',
        ),
     )
    )
```

and modify the fields you want

Comment: Thanks, Sina. I'm not using Doctrine but I did already direct 'user_entity_class' to my new entity in my zfcuser global config, and that part seems to be working well.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav I didn't accept the answer because it doesn't actually resolve the issue. I was already using my own entity for users, but it doesn't work if the fields aren't in the database table itself, which was my question.

Comment: @sarahg why !? ... can u update your question with your code and exact error?